# How to change the background color of checkbox when it is checked and also changed to reset when it is unchecked from checked status?

Tags: html, css

How to change the background color of parent node of the check box when it is checked and change it back to default when its unchecked from checked status ?

Comment: You could provide a sample of your current work, what have you tried and what (if) you are using, like jQuery or plain JavaScript. Better yet, [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, uou can try the on click event for your checkbox, like below:

```
$(document).on('click', '#checkbox-id', function(event){     

    // Determine if the checkbox is checked or not
    $checked = $("#checkbox-id").is(':checked');        

    // Change background color of the parent node
    if($checked)
        $(this).parent().css("background-color","yellow");
    else
        $(this).parent().css("background-color","white");
});
```

Comment: thank you buddy but there is one problem that this code runs only first time checked and unchecked after this it doesn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CDA2u/2/)

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            span.addClass('checked');

        }
        $(this).wrap(span).hide();
    });

    function doCheck() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).css("background-color","white");
            $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
        }
    }

    function doDown() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
    }

    function doUp() {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.checkbox, .radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    background: url("http://i48.tinypic.com/raz13m.jpg");
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
 }

.checked {
     background-position: 0px -50px;   
}

.clicked {
     background-position: 0px -25px;
}

.clicked.checked {
     background-position: 0px -75px;
}

.green {
    background-color: white;
 }
```

HTML Code

```
<p><input type="checkbox" name="1" class="styled green"/> (green)</p>
```

Just check the click event and change the css. This will do the trick.